# Android, SQLite update, getting empty values BUT it isn´t?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to use the update, but I get a throw saying that values are empty :/ but according to android studio they are there

The code:

```
int tempDay = tempCursor.getColumnIndex("count");
                            int tempDayTotal = tempDay + entry.getValue();
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put("count", Integer.toString(tempDayTotal));
                            cv.put("dayActive", Integer.toString(1));
                            GVars.dBase.conn.update("clientProduct", cv, "clientID = ? AND productID = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(tempIDClient),Integer.toString(entry.getKey().getId())});
```

This is what I get when I tell the android studio to enter into this function:

[image: Print Screen of the android studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the name of count to countDay and it fixed all